# Example of continuous from above measure space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to find an example of a measure space ($X, \mathcal F$) with measure $\mu$ that is continuous from above ($A_{i+1}\subset A_{i}$), its intersection is the empty set ($\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i=\emptyset$) and its measure doesn't tend to $0$ ($\mu(A_n)\nrightarrow0$) as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you mean an example of a sequence of sets in some measure space?

Comment: I thought the same when I read the statement, but no, that is the question.

Comment: Do you mean a measure that is NOT continuous from above?

Comment: I revised the question and it has to be continuous from above, I think that the objective is to prove that such function doesn't exist, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If $(X, \mathscr{X}, \mu)$ has finite positive measure, then it will do the trick. You probably already know that $\mu(B_n) \to \mu(B)$ if $B_n \uparrow B.$ Take $B_n = A_n^\complement,$ so that $B_n \uparrow X$ since $A_n \downarrow \varnothing,$ then $P(A_n) = 1 - P(B_n) \downarrow 1 - 1 = 0 = P(\varnothing).$

In infinite dimensions, this is not true. Consider $A_n = (n, \infty),$ on $\mathbf{R},$ so that $\lambda(A_n) = \infty$ ($\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure) yet $A_n \downarrow \varnothing.$

Comment: I assumed $X$ to have total measure equal to 1, this is possible since if $\mu$ is any positive finite measure, then $\hat \mu = \frac{1}{\mu(X)} \mu$ is another measure, equivalent to $\mu,$ on $X$ that has total mass equal to 1. Additionally, all convergences by $\mu$ are equivalent to those by $\hat \mu.$

Comment: Thanks, however, as far as I understand this is a proof of non-existence of such space? since the measure always tend to $0$ if we have a non finite measure.

Comment: It is very different to ask for the proof that something does not exists vs asking for an example where something does not happen. I am pretty sure you are confusing these two.